# Driving a larger motor with a signal from a small motor

Tags: transistors, mosfet, motor, dc-dc-converter, voltage-divider

I am repurposing a remote control car.
I want to attach a larger 18 V, 2Amp windshield wiper motor to the receiver.
The original motor was a small 5V DC.
I sadly do not have datasheets for any of these components.
They are brushed DC motors, the receiver board is some toy RC car. Everything second hand without labels.

I am thinking about using a voltage divider, so I can drive the 5 V receiver and LM with the same 18 V, 3.5 A Laptop charger, stripped to supply DC.
I am considering using a ~1000 & ~400ohm resistor to get the voltage down for the receiver board.
Is there something I should take into account?

What is the best way to transform the 5V that drove the old Motor to 18V for the larger motor?

I tried a combination of 4 transistors, attaching the cables of the old motor to the bases of the transistors hoping that when the direction changes, the positive current will unlock half of the transistors, and let the electricity go in the right direction over the larger motor.

I had both systems on different power supplies (to not short the board if i made a mistake), and it didn't work.

Edit: This is my naive approach
[image]

Before anyone suggests using PWM: my goal is to use the simplest electrical components.

Comment: Show your circuit that you tried. What is OM and LM? Please provide data sheet links to the motors and receiver.

Comment: That is not signal *from* a smaller motor, but *for*. There are two interpretations to *most simple* - to use: a fitting motor/"speed" controller wit BEC: BatteryEliminationCircuit. Or from most basic components - wire, metal sheets & transistors: good luck.

Comment: A laptop charger isn't (quite) a *power supply*.

Comment: LM is the large motor, OM is the original motor
yes i mean the signal for the smaller motor should drive the larger motor. i just found out about dc-dc converters. I guess thats what i need?

Comment: @greybeard what do you mean a laptopcharger is not quite a powersupply? it is what i had. it delivers the voltage and amps at controlled level

Comment: @Andyaka i dont have datasheets. The LM is an old car window wiper, and the OM is a small dc motor from a remote controlled car.

Comment: (*charger* vs. PS: What I'd call an "electronics" power supply would output a constant DC voltage. What I'd accept as a laptop *charger* would be something suitable to directly charge a laptop battery - I'm aware use in advertising/marketing deviates (occurs where adapter or PS would be less inaccurate). With contemporary Li cells, *suitable* would include terminating when the "charging" current falls below some threshold - I'd prefer that *not* to happen with a PS.)

Comment: @greybeard as stated before electronics is a bit of black magic for me, but a laptop charger has 3 cables, two of them supply the power, one is a data cable. Probably for the use you mentioned. I am only using the ground and power cable and completely detached the data cable to always get the full voltage